# Expanded notification layout attributes can not be found 'No resource identifier found for attribute'

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, schema

I'm using the big image notification template as provided in the SDK (xml below). But I'm unable to compile my project after I have added this layout.

Even though I'm using the Schema: `http://schemas.android.com/apk/prv/res/android` which should provide `layout_minHeight` and `layout_maxHeight`.

Why do I have this problem and how can it be fixed?

> Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_minHeight' in package 'android'
>
> Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'layout_maxHeight' in package 'android'

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:internal="http://schemas.android.com/apk/prv/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/status_bar_latest_event_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    internal:layout_minHeight="65dp"
    internal:layout_maxHeight="unbounded"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/big_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/title_bar_shadow"
        />
    <include layout="@layout/notification_template_material_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        />
  <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/notification_large_icon_width"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#CCEEEEEE"
        >
        <include
            layout="@layout/notification_material_action_list"
            android:id="@+id/actions"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/notification_template_material_big_picture.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change `xmlns:internal="http://schemas.android.com/apk/prv/res/android"` to `xmlns:internal="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`